# Redirect all pages to index.php

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to redirect all pages to `index.php` and serve all content from the `index.php`.

I currently have this in my `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ /p/index.php [L,QSA]
```

When I go to `example.com/p/xxxx` (not existing php file) it goes to `/p/index.php` exactly as I would like it.

However, if I go to `example.com/p/home` it serves the `/p/home.php` file and I want it to go to `/p/index.php`.

The `.htaccess` file is in the `/p/` folder.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to disable MultiViews (part of mod_negotiation). If MultiViews is enabled and `/p/home.php` exists (when you request `/p/home`) then that file will be served. MultiViews essentially enables extensionless URLs, but conflicts with mod_rewrite as it is processed first.

For example, at the top of your `.htaccess` file:

```
Options -MultiViews
```

Otherwise, your existing mod_rewrite directives are OK.

---

**update:**

> The `.htaccess` file is in the `/p/` folder.

Your directives could be simplified/optimised a bit...

```
RewriteRule ^index\.php - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

The relative substitution string is relative to the directory that contains the `.htaccess` file, so you don't need to explicitly include the `/p` directory in the substitution. The `QSA` flag is not required, since you are not appending a query string in the substitution.

The regex `.` is more optimal than `^.*$` since you don't need to match everything, you just need to be successful if there is *something*. When the URL-path is empty then the `DirectoryIndex` (mod_dir) will serve `index.php`.

The first rule is simply an optimisation that prevents rewritten requests from undergoing the filesystem check (which is relatively expensive).

Comment: Correction... should be `Options` (with an `s`), not `Option`!

Comment: Thanks! You mean "Options" I guess, but that looks to be it!

Comment: @user1864797 Yes, typo... I've updated my answer.

Comment: @user1864797 You're welcome. If this answered your question then please mark it as "accepted" by clicking the tick/checkmark next to the answer on the left below the voting arrows (to help other users, remove the question from the unanswered question queue and to show your appreciation ;). You can also upvote answers you find helpful. Thanks, much appreciated. :)